# Magento pagination

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to show some pagination here. It shows the 60 products. How can I for example show 20 on each page?

Thanks

```
//$_productCollection = $this->getLoadedProductCollection();
$_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
$resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
$readConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_read'); 
//$query = 'SELECT cid FROM tees_user_login_table WHERE ((group_id = 1 and status = 1 and cid > 0) or (group_id in (2,3,4,5) and include_new = 1 and status = 1))';
$query = 'SELECT cid FROM tees_user_login_table WHERE status = 1 and include_new = 1';
$results = $readConnection->fetchAll($query);
$categoryIds = array() ;

foreach ($results as $k => $v) {
    $categoryIds[] = $v['cid'] ;
}

$this->setProductsCount(60) ;
$_productCollection = $this
    ->getProductCollection()
    ->setPageSize($this->getProductsCount())
    ->addAttributeToSelect(array(
        'name',
        'price',
        'special_price',
        'sku',
        'small_image'
    ))
    ->joinField('category_id',  // add category ID field to collection
         'catalog_category_product',
         'category_id',
         'product_id=entity_id',
         null,
         'left'
    )
    ->groupByAttribute('sku')   
    ->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('in' => $categoryIds));
```

Comment: Where is this file? phtml? What is the block?

Comment: new.phtml 

{{block type="catalog/product_new" limit="48" template="catalog/product/new.phtml"}}

Comment: What can I add to my answer to make it correct?

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

Replace `$this->setProductsCount(60) ;` with `$this->setProductsCount(20) ;`.

Or whatever value you want.

---

The `$this->setProductsCount(60) ;` is used to control the limit of the query, `->setPageSize($this->getProductsCount())`,and probably the layout of the page.

---

Finally, and not directly relevant to the question, the *Magento* way to make this type of modification would be in the block.